# Why notification sound for API Level 26 and above not working?

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.1-nougat

I have this app  where i want set custom notification sound,

i have this method that check android version and create notification accordingly..

on android 6 and lower it works fine and playing the custom sound.

**but on android 7 and above its not playing the custom notification sound that i want**

1- none of the answer on stack-overflow could solve this issue

2- my code is wrote in the best way as android developers docs specifies

3- my file is .wav and its 44100HZ

> here is the code, What i am missing ?

```
private void createLocalNotificationx(Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    Uri alarmSound;

    if (type.equals(VALUE_ROUTINE)) {
        alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alarm);
    } else {
        alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                + "://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.emergency);
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(alarmSound).setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Log.d(TAG, "alarmSound =" + alarmSound.getPath());
        /*First create the notification channel:*/
        String CHANNEL_ID = getPackageName() + "/ID";
        String name = getString(R.string.app_name);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 500});
        mChannel.enableLights(true);

        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();


        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotification);

    }

}
```

note : it could be cleaner code but it should be fine !

Comment: mChannel.setSound(alarm), and mNotification.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)

Answer (score 0):

From "Oreo" onwards you can't set custom tone to a notification. But you can set a custom tone to a specific channel. All the notifications for that channel will have this custom notification tone.
To setup tone to a channel follow below:

```
 NotificationChannel reminderChannel = new NotificationChannel(<id>,
            context.getString(R.string.id), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    reminderChannel.setDescription(context.getString(R.string.desc));
    reminderChannel.enableLights(true);
    reminderChannel.enableVibration(true);
    // Creating an Audio Attribute
    AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
            .build();
    Uri alarmSound;
    alarmSound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + HealthifymeApp.getInstance().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.reminder_notification);
    reminderChannel.setSound(alarmSound, audioAttributes);
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(reminderChannel);
```

Comment: Additionally, your targetSdkVersion must be >= 26.

Comment: If user made a custom changes to that channel notification properties, your settings won't work anymore, even after update.

Answer (score -1):

take a look at your `.setDefaults()` method:

```
Notification mNotification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
```

probably `Notification.DEFAULT_ALL` is causing your problem.

Comment: @farisfaris I wasn't suggesting its removal, try changing Notification.DEFAULT_ALL

Comment: i changed to  Notification.DEFAULT_ALL  and still playing the default sound!

Comment: @farisfaris by changing it I meant replacing it with other values, when it is set to DEFAULT_ALL it automatically uses all default notification settings of your device.